# Is this try pattern to fetch entities from a chess board, easy to follow?

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a game of chess, and, more specifically, I'm creating the code for the game board. The board is simply a static class that contains a multi-dimensional array representing the board, and methods to interact with it. The method in question for the purposes of *this* question, is called `TryGetEntity`:

```
private static GameEntity[,] _board = new GameEntity[8,8];
...
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity) {
    occupyingEntity = null;
    if (_board.GetLength(0) < requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) < requestedPosition.Y)
        return false;
    
    if (_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y] != null)
        occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
    else return false;
    return true;
}
```

My concern with this implementation is the default return value of `true`. I've been taught over many years to assume failure which loosely translates to returning `false` by default. Currently, I'm at war with myself on refactoring this to:

```
occupyingEntity = null;
if (_board.GetLength(0) >= requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) >= requestedPosition.Y) {
    if (_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y] != null) {
        occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

I personally think that the second version reads better, but I'm wanting a second (or more) opinion on it.

---

***Edit**: Per request from the comments, here is the entire `GameBoard` class, along with an example use-case (this project is still in very early phases, so no actual calls exist yet):*

```
public static class GameBoard {
    private static GameEntity[,] _board = new GameEntity[8,8];
    public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity) {
        occupyingEntity = null;
        if (_board.GetLength(0) >= requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) >= requestedPosition.Y) {
            if (_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y] != null) {
                occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

// Example use-case:
var requestedCoordinate = new BoardCoordinate(3, 3);
if (GameBoard.TryGetEntity(requestedCoordinate, out GameEntity occupyingPiece))
    CapturePiece(occupyingPiece);
else
    MoveToPosition(requestedCoordinate);
```

---

Does this implementation of the try pattern, in its originally presented state, seem easy to follow? How about the second version?

***Edit**: I **think**, that by posting this question, I sort-of answered it. Given that it made me stop and seek a second opinion in its original state, I suspect the same would be true for others. Additionally, now that I've gotten some sleep, the first version is much harder to read than the second. It's not more complex, just, cluttered and doing too much. I'll keep this question up for others to answer in greater detail, but I'm not going to be surprised if the consensus is "the first method is harder to read".*

<sub>***Note**: Let's ignore formatting for this post.*</sub>

Comment: Any an all critiques of the code should be posted in answers. Posting critiques of the code in comments are subject to removal for being a violation of the [commenting privilege](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) - "Comments are not recommended for any of the following: Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First version:

- You shouldn't omit braces, `{}`, although they might be optional, because that can lead to hidden and therefore hard-to-track bugs. Having braces helps structuring the code as well.
- Instead of the `else` you just could return early inside the `if` block and have a `return false;` afterwards.

This would result in

```
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity)
{
    occupyingEntity = null;
    if (_board.GetLength(0) < requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) < requestedPosition.Y)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y] != null)
    {
        occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

which is IMO easy to read.

The second version:

Well, I think the nested `if`s are hurting readability. I would at least keep the first `if` separately and would change the ..... no, forget it. I would just take the first version and change it like so

```
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity)
{
    occupyingEntity = null;
    if (_board.GetLength(0) < requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) < requestedPosition.Y)
    {
        return false;
    }

    occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
    return occupyingEntity != null;
}
```

Comment: Just because you _can_ add braces everywhere doesn't mean you _have to_. When you have lots of `if... else if ... else if ... else` and they're all one-liners, you double the length by adding the redundant braces. I agree, though, that if at least one of the `if`'s needs the braces, the whole block should get them.

Answer (score 9):

Yes the code is readable.

I'm curious why you feel you need multiple return statements. The return statement can return a boolean expression.

```
public static class GameBoard
{
    private static GameEntity[,] _board = new GameEntity[8, 8];
    public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity)
    {
        occupyingEntity = null;
        if (_board.GetLength(0) >= requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) >= requestedPosition.Y)
        {
            if (_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y] != null)
            {
                occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
            }
        }

        return occupyingEntity != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I *think* I wrote it that way due to lack of sleep and all the while trying to be explicit with the intent of the code. By far, I like this approach **much** more than my initial version. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: IMHO this is a bad solution. `_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y]` gets used twice, plus there is a second level of `if` and that second level isn't even necessary since if `_board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y]` is null, there is no danger in assigning that value to `occupyingEntity` anyway.

Comment: @BCdotWEB IMHO, this answer is true to the message it's trying to convey, regardless of the redundant array access. The takeaway here is to return an expression instead of utilizing multiple return statements. As such, I wouldn't say this is a bad solution, in-fact, it's a great solution; it just has an oversight on the redundancy.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know C#, but this is what Nullable types are for. From what I can tell, they obsolete the `TryX`+`out` parameter combination.

So your method signature should be more like:

```
public static GameEntity? GetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition)
```

Where you either return a valid GameEntity directly, or just `return null`.

Comment: Not sure if this was the answer you were speaking on earlier, but it's a great point. Since you pointed out that you're not well versed in C#, I'd like to point out that `GameEntity` is a reference type, and as such it is null by default. However, it would be good practice if I added explicit declaration that `null` is permitted within my method by using the nullable annotation `GameEntity?` as you suggest. +1

Comment: @Tacoタコス Yep, and then you get a nicer syntax at the callsite :)

Comment: A significant amount of the time, enough to feel like always, when I program (in Python) I use `if None is not (value := foo.get(bar)):`. I did like C# having `tryGet` because it'd make all those if statements quite a bit nicer IMO - `if foo.tryGet(bar, value):`. Ultimately I think providing _both_ a `tryGet` and `get` gives the user the ability to pick the nicest option for the situation.

Comment: Try to beat `if (board.TryGetPiece( position, out var piece ))` in terms of nice syntax with `Nullable` and lots of `?`... perhaps in the future, but right now you can't even write `piece?.Color = red;`

Comment: "but right now you can't even write `piece?.Color = red;`" Has that syntax not shipped yet?

Comment: @Haukinger `?.` is pretty good in C#. Additionally if you need `?.{foo} = {bar}` then you're just abusing `null`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz don't get me wrong, `?.` is great, no discussion whatsoever. Why do you think `if (foo != null) foo.Something = bar;` is abusing `null`?

Comment: @Haukinger If you're needing `?.{foo} = {bar}` to the point nulls are not nice then the objects in your code are partially initialized. I had similar ideas back when I was a noob and had partially initialized state all over my code. One place where it could be compelling is a REST microservice which mutates the output of another REST service, but using dictionaries and lists with a FP/MP approach is better than building objects.

Comment: @Peilonrayz exactly. I'd never use properties for building objects (except for the new init-only-properties). _Changing_ an object's property is completely fine, though, from one valid state to another. In this case, `nullable?.Property = newValue;` is a nice shorthand to hide an `if` when [issue 2883](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2883) is implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Your first version of `TryGetEntity` essentially follows this structure:

```
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate x, out GameEntity ret) {
    ret = null;
    if (condition1)
        return false;
    
    if (! condition2)
        ret = value;
    else return false;
    return true;
}
```

It’s otherwise clean, but this structure is just … weirdly inconsistent. Why not write the conditions as consistent guard clauses with early exits, and put the successful code path at the end (saving one `else` in the process)?

```
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate x, out GameEntity ret) {
    ret = null;

    if (condition1)
        return false;
    if (condition2)
        return false;
    
    ret = value;
    return true;
}
```

This makes the logic much more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

To me the code presented by @pacmaninbw is close to what I would write, but I would simplify it to avoid the second if-statement giving:

```
public static bool TryGetEntity(BoardCoordinate requestedPosition, out GameEntity occupyingEntity) {
     occupyingEntity = null;

     if (_board.GetLength(0) >= requestedPosition.X || _board.GetLength(1) >= requestedPosition.Y) {
          occupyingEntity = _board[requestedPosition.X, requestedPosition.Y];
     }

     return occupyingEntity != null;
}
```

I also find that this style of `{...}` is less impactful making it easier to consistently add it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know C# but this is how I would write the code

```
public static class GameBoard {
    private static GameEntity[,] _board = new GameEntity[8,8];
    public static GameEntity TryGetEntity(x, y) {
        if (_board.GetLength(0) < x && _board.GetLength(1) > y)
            return null;
        
        return _board[x, y];
    }
}

// Example use-case:
GameEntity occupyingPiece = GameBoard.TryGetEntity(3,3);
if (occupyingPiece != null)
    CapturePiece(occupyingPiece);
else
    MoveToPosition(3,3);
```

Syntax might not be 100% correct, as I said I don't know much C#, but the theme should be the same:

1. Do your checks and return null rather than true/false
2. Check for null on return, better on a variable than on a function
3. Coordinates class seemed redundant

Without seeing your entire code something tells me that your choice of statics is a bit exaggerated.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, and welcome to CodeReview! The try pattern is designed to return a boolean value indicating if the attempt was successful or not. It’s great to explicitly check for null after getting the value back out, though if the method returns false, we already know the output is invalid and as such, within the scope of the use-case, we don’t use the it.

Comment: @Tacoタコスreturning a boolean result and a value makes redundant code/logic and makes the program prone to errors. If the function returns false then the returned value must be null, and if the function returns true then the returned value must not be null. Any other scenario (which can happen with the original code) is wrong and would require development time tracing the problem.
I will admit that I am not familiar with a 'try pattern', is it a design pattern? Even if it is, design patterns are guidelines or skeleton structures and can/should be adapted where it makes sense.

Comment: @slepax It’s an established pattern in C#. Yes, there are better modern solutions but the API pattern is from a time before C# supported those. To stay consistent with those APIs, the pattern persists, and it’s best practice to follow it. At any rate the pattern really isn’t error-prone at all, just unnecessarily verbose.